# CryptoJS: Converting encryption result to hex, then back, then can no longer decrypt the data

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I'm encoding some text using CryptoES (identical API/functionality to CryptoJS), then decoding it as a check/test as I go along. The following code successfully encodes and then decodes some input:

```
const dataToEncrypt = "something";    
const encryptionKeyAsHexString = "2EE1F10212ADD4BEB0E9FED2FEA24733";
const ivAsHexString = "B8C67C19F6E3AE23D4E11E5B376FA891"; 
  
const encryptedData = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(dataToEncrypt, CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptionKeyAsHexString), { 
      mode: CryptoES.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoES.pad.Pkcs7, 
      iv: CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(ivAsHexString)
  }
);

const decryptedCheck1 = CryptoES.AES.decrypt( encryptedData,   CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptionKeyAsHexString), {
  mode: CryptoES.mode.CBC, 
  padding: CryptoES.pad.Pkcs7,
  iv: CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(ivAsHexString) 
} );
const decryptedCheck1Text = decryptedCheck1.toString( CryptoES.enc.Utf8 );
console.log("decryptedCheck1Text:  ", decryptedCheck1Text);
```

However if I add an extra step to the above code to hex encode the encrypted data, then I can no longer decrypt it using the following code:

```
const encryptedData = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(dataToEncrypt, CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptionKeyAsHexString), { 
          mode: CryptoES.mode.CBC,
          padding: CryptoES.pad.Pkcs7, 
          iv: CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(ivAsHexString)
      }
    );
    
// Convert the encrypted data to hex
const encryptedDataAsHexString =  CryptoES.enc.Hex.stringify(encryptedData.ciphertext);
    
const decryptedCheck2 = CryptoES.AES.decrypt( CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedDataAsHexString), CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptionKeyAsHexString), {
      mode: CryptoES.mode.CBC, 
      padding: CryptoES.pad.Pkcs7,
          iv: CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(ivAsHexString) 
      } 
);
        
const decryptedCheck2Text = decryptedCheck2.toString( CryptoES.enc.Utf8 );
console.log("decryptedCheck2Text: ", decryptedCheck2Text);
```

In the second block of code `encryptedData.ciphertext` is converted to Hex the result of which is passed to the `decrypt()` function as `CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedDataAsHexString)` which ought to reverse the hexing?

But something is incorrect and there is nothing in `decryptedCheck2Text`. Why is the second chunk of code no longer working to decrypt the data?

I've experimented with several variant (such as using CryptoES.enc.Hex.stringify(encryptedData) instead of just the .cipherText part) but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found it was necessary to base64 encode the hex before passing it as a parameter, like this:

```
const tempWordArray = CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedDataAsHexString);
const tempBase64 = CryptoES.enc.Base64.stringify(tempWordArray)
  const decryptedCheck2 = CryptoES.AES.decrypt( tempBase64, CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(encryptionKeyAsHexString)
  ...
```